How to unit test a collection with a private method checking the end of the collection is reached
I know this is probably basic stuff but if I have a private field collection that is initialised in a constructor e.g.
public blah()
{
  _brushes = new List<Brush> { Brushes.Red, Brushes.Blue, Brushes.Green };
}

and then I have a method that sets this (but does loads of other stuff too) e.g.
public CreateModel(){
// does stuff
_model.Brush = GetNextBrush();
// does stuff
}

and then a private method e.g.
private Brush GetNextBrush()
{
  var brush = _brushes[_index];
  _index++;

  if (_index == _brushes.Count)
  {
    _index = 0;
  }
  
  return brush;
}

What is the appropriate way to unit test this? Extract out the brushes into a service with an interface and pass this into the constructor? Just seems overkill but I'm probably missing something. I don't want to make the method public - seems wrong.
Many thanks
-Jeni
Bigger excerpt:
public class vm : IViewModel
{
  private readonly List<Brush> _brushes;
  private int _brushIndex;
  private readonly _modelCollection;

  public vm(IModelCollection modelCollection)
  {
    _modelCollection = modelCollection;
    _brushes = new List<Brush> { Brushes.Red, Brushes.Blue, Brushes.Green };
  }

  public void AddSig(ISigModel sigModel)
  {    
    _model.Brush = GetNextBrush();
    if (sigModel.IsAtt)
    {
      sigModel.Process = "StartEvent";
    }
    _modelCollection.AddSig(sigModel);
    StartCSUpdatingEvent();
  }

    private Brush GetNextBrush()
    {
      var brush = _brushes[_index];
      _index++;
    
      if (_index == _brushes.Count)
      {
        _index = 0;
      }
      
      return brush;
    }
}


Please provide a [mcve]. Currently you've provided snippets of pseudocode, some of which wouldn't compile, and that makes it very hard to know what the visible effect of calling CreateModel() is. Could you write a unit test that calls CreateModel() twice, and checks that the brushes in the two created models are different, for example?

Also mind that you could use modulo % : _index = (_index+1)%_brushes.Count;

Are both blah() and CreateModel() constructors of different classes? Which class contains the method GetNextBrush()?

I'd probably create a dedicated class: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Irqtmo or similar. Makes it testable and a separated unit of concern. Your ViewModel doesn't need to know, how you pick the next brush.

A solution is to move GetNextBrush() into a separate class, that has only one resposibility: To generate the next brush.
public class BrushGenerator
{
   private List<Brush> _brushes = new List<Brush> { Brushes.Red, Brushes.Blue, Brushes.Green };

   private int _index = 0;

   public Brush GetNextBrush()
   {
     var brush = _brushes[_index];
     _index++;

     if (_index == _brushes.Count)
     {
        _index = 0;
     }
  
    return brush;
  }
}

In your class that contains CreateModel(), you can create an instance of this class:
private BrushGenerator _brushGenerator = new BrushGenerator();
public CreateModel(){
// does stuff
_model.Brush = _brushGenerator .GetNextBrush();
// does stuff
}

Now you can write a unit test just for your BrushGenerator class (with MSTest in this example):
[DataRow(1, Brushes.Red)]
[DataRow(2, Brushes.Blue)]
[DataRow(3, Brushes.Green)]
[DataRow(4, Brushes.Red)]
[DataTestMethod]
public void CorrectBrushIsReturned(int times, Brushes expectedBrush)
{
   var brushGenerator = new BrushGenerator();
   Brushes result = Brushes.None;

   for(int i = 0; i < times; i++)
   {
      result = brushGenerator.GetNextBrush();
   }

   Assert.AreEqual(expectedBrush, result);
}


It's quite easy to make GetNextBrush threadsafe, so I'd recommend doing that.

If the brushes are private, how can I write a test to ensure the GetNextBrush always returns the first brush when at the last index, regardless of how many brushes are declared. Would I need to make _brushes public so the test can get the count. Or should I create a separate brushes class with just the brushes?

I understood the code you provided in a way that the brushes are hard-coded - always the same three brushes. If brushes can change during runtime, you can make the list public. This will make your tests much more complex. You will get new test cases (e.g. what happens if brushes are generated, hence _index>0, a new brush is added to the list?) But this is a  new question.

I ended up creating another class that was responsibile only for defining the list of brushes, then this could be injected into the BrushGenerator which means in my tests I can create a mock of whatever list of brushes I want and test accordingly. Seems to work ok. thanks

Test the public behavior of your "Module".
In this case the "Module" might be a class, but can also be a collection of classes, a single method, or an entire application. The key thing is that the module is as isolated as possible from other modules.
In your specific example the GetNextBrush method seem to be be used to distribute colors for different models, and I would assume that the created model and used brushes are somehow externally visible, otherwise, what is the point. So create say a hundred models and check that the use count of the least and most used color differ by at most one, or that there is no repeated color, or whatever invariant it is you want to fulfill.
I would recommend against checking that each model gets a specific color, because things like colors tend to change, and you want to avoid having to update your tests for any little change to the implementation.
Also keep in mind that the usefulness and cost of automatic tests varies, and not all things are practical to test. High complexity tend to increase the usefulness of tests, while dependencies tend to increase the cost.
